# TypeScript array definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having such simple JS objects definitions:

```
...
const Post1 : TPost = {
    title: "Post One",
    body: "This is the Post One"
}

const Post2 : TPost = {
    title: "Post Two",
    body: "This is the Post Two"
}
...
```

and such `TyprScript` `TPost` type definition:

```
interface TPost  { 
    title: string,
    body: string
}
```

One can define a TPosts type like that

```
type TPosts = TPost[];
```

My question is how to do that - define `TPosts` as an array of `TPost` objects using the `Interface` syntax?

Comment: `type TPosts = TPost[];` is correct for making `TPosts` an array of `TPost`. So, I'm not sure I understand the question. Note that *normally* you don't declare a type for an array of something, the notation `X[]` is most often used. Not necessarily for technical reasons but it does make it easier to understand what the type is without needing to look it up, if you see `Xs` you won't necessarily know it's an array of `X`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```js
const TPosts: TPost[] = [
    Post1,
    Post2,
]
```

Specifying array types for variables is the same as for normal variables, you only need to add `[]`.

Comment: Ok Bob, but I'd like to specify that the `TPosts` type is an array of objects of type `TPost`, not just array of concrete instances `Post1` & `Post2`. I'd like to be more generic/universal with the `TPosts` definition.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know your usecase but i guess this should help.

```
interface TPost  { 
    title: string,
    body: string
}

const tposts: TPost[] = [
    {
    title: "Post One",
    body: "This is the Post One"
    },
    {
    title: "Post Two",
    body: "This is the Post Two"
    },
]
```

Comment: array of objects of type `TPost`, not just array of concrete instances `Post1` & `Post2`. I'd like to be more generic/universal with the `TPosts` definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but here it is:

```js
interface TPosts {
    tposts: TPost[]
}
```

Still I think this is not a good way to approach...